# How to get only the real solutions in Maxima?

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I am trying to solve an equation with Maxima so that I only get real solutions if they exist; if there are no real solutions, or if there are not even complex solutions, I would like Maxima to return an empty list.

For example, I would like that when solving `x^2+100-x=0` using `solve(x^2+100-x,x)`, which has only complex solutions, Maxima would return an empty list. Or that when solving `log(x)-x=0` using `solve(log(x)-x,x)`, which also has no real solutions, Maxima would return an empty list. In this second example, what I get instead is `[x=log(x)]`.

How could this be achieved with Maxima?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inhibit implicit solutions:

```
(%i1) solve(log(x)-x);
(%o1)                            [x = log(x)]
(%i2) solve(log(x)-x), solveexplicit: true;
(%o2)                                 []
```

Keep only solutions without an imaginary part:

```
(%i1) s: solve(x^2+100-x);
                       sqrt(399) %i - 1      sqrt(399) %i + 1
(%o1)           [x = - ----------------, x = ----------------]
                              2                     2
(%i2) sublist(s, imagpart);
(%o2)                                 []
(%i3) s: solve(x^2+2 * x + 1);
(%o3)                              [x = - 1]
(%i4) sublist(s, imagpart);
(%o4)                              [x = - 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves the problem! Maybe you could take a look at this related question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71615022/how-to-get-only-the-real-solutions-in-maxima. I tried `solve(sin(x)-x), solveexplicit: true` but it still does not work with trigonometric equations...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could also help your answer:

> (%i80)    realroots(x^2+100-x=0);
>
> (%o80)   []

when the solution is [], there no real roots. On the other hand, when at least there is a real solution:

> (%i7) realroots (x^3-3*x^2+4*x-2 = 0);
>
> (%o7) [x=1]

x^3-3*x^2+4*x-2 = 0 have three solution, only one is real. For all solution:

> (%i9) solve(x^3-3*x^2+4*x-2 = 0,x);
>
> (%o9) [x=1-%i,x=%i+1,x=1]